# Display Existing PDF file inside TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I use TCPDF to create pdf pages in my website, i had successfully created pdf file using TCPDF, but now the problem is i have to display already existing pdf file(user uploaded pdf file located in server directory - now local host) in the generated TCPDF pdf file.. i tried the  code but it didn't work... the example code is given below..

```
    $journals_page='
    <embed>
    type="application/pdf"
    src="./uploads/publications/hi.pdf"
    width="100%"
    height="100%">
    </embed>
    ';
$html = ''.$journals_page;
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

I use writeHTML() type pdf in TCPDF.. the Pages created prior to this are working perfectly.. but i can't display the pdf file.. Pls help me with a solution to this problem.. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
header("Location:path/to/hi.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  tag of your iframe page to prevent it from download.

tag is new media elements now valid in html5

Link tcpdf.php on src attribute of

```
<html>
<body>
<embed
type="application/pdf"
src="http://yoursite.com/tcpdf/tcpdf.php″
width="100%"
height="100%">
</embed>
</body>
</html>
```